# Spring boot application doesn't run Tomcat in docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat, containers

I have spring boot rest api application written in Java. I use @SpringBootApplication annotation, build.gradle contains following items:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.1.2" 

    }

group = 'commandexecutor'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

shadowJar { 
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    mergeServiceFiles()
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': 'demo.main',
                'Main-Class': 'commandexecutor.demo.DemoApplication'
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

When I run my app locally at IDE - everything is fine, but when I run it in docker container - I get status exited after 5-6 sec (because tomcat didn't start, see screenshot above). I'm very confused why tomcat is starting locally successfully, but at container - not. What is the root cause of such differences?

Comment: How did you create the container? And what's the purpose of shadowJar? boot builds executable jars already (`bootJar` task - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable)

Comment: There's also some documentation on how you could create containers from boot applications, even directly from gradle if you want: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker

Comment: Does it write any error to the tomcat log in the container before exiting?